# ASP.NET Telerik Grid design

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

One (design) thing, in Firefox the page looks different than on Internet Explorer. I don't have any clue why. Can you help me with some suggestion why can this happen? I tried to change width of the column but no success :(
Thank you!

Firefox :
(Grid flows a little bit into the menu bar to the right)
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1RvHHd8Tp6JVXlQLW84ck1DQ1k/edit
[pic1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1RvHHd8Tp6JVXlQLW84ck1DQ1k/edit)

Internet Explorer :
(Grid width is correct but the row “Stand” is not big enough)
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1RvHHd8Tp6JeElVSzJ2dGFpVEk/edit
[pic2](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1RvHHd8Tp6JeElVSzJ2dGFpVEk/edit)

Comment: You might change the default font size for the telerik grids, since you're having issues getting all your columns into the container width. If you don't want items to wrap in a table grid, use `white-space:nowrap;`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will take this into account in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It was the text in header row - too large and width of the grid was auto resized.

Best Regards